# Stop Input From Inheriting Another Input's Value On Button Click

Tags: javascript, html, input

I'm creating a post slug input, so when editing post title input it'll inherit it's value to the disabled slug input amd there is a button when clicking it enables the disabled input. It is working good, but I want on clicking the button it'll stop Inheriting values.
Here is my code :

```
<input type="text" id="a"/>
<input type="text" id="b" disabled/>
<button id="btn">Stop</button>
<script>
    document.querySelector('#a').addEventListener('keyup', () => {
        document.querySelector('#b').value = document.querySelector('#a').value;
    });
    
    document.querySelector('#btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
        document.querySelector('#b').disabled = false;
    });
</script>
```

I've googled, but i haven't found.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `removeEventListener` of the `a` element `keyup` after clicking the button.

```js
    function onAKeyup() {
        document.querySelector('#b').value = document.querySelector('#a').value;
    }
    
    document.querySelector('#a').addEventListener('keyup', onAKeyup);
    
    document.querySelector('#btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
        document.querySelector('#b').disabled = false;
        document.querySelector('#a').removeEventListener('keyup', onAKeyup)
    });
```

```html
<input type="text" id="a"/>
<input type="text" id="b" disabled/>
<button id="btn">Stop</button>
```